# XNA wp7 gesture detection issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0, gesture

I have to use both type of input in my app (gestures and simple touch). And i got a problem with it. For example i use double tap gesture and before it detected i have one detection of simple touch. This in not that way i expect, because simple touch has its own logic, which brings me lot of problems. The same issue with Drag, before detecting drag again first decetced simple touch. How can i handle gestures without handling simple touch logic.
Here the way im trying to do that:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.DoubleTap | GestureType.VerticalDrag;
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            isGesture = true;
            GestureSample gestureSample = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            switch (gestureSample.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.DoubleTap:

                    //some logic
                    break;
                case GestureType.HorizontalDrag:
                    //some logic
                    break;
            }
        }


        if (Consts.TouchCollection.Count == 1) 
        {
            var touch = Consts.TouchCollection[0]; //here needed only first touch

            switch (touch.State)
            {
                case TouchLocationState.Pressed:
                     //This one called first if used double tap

                    break;
                case TouchLocatiomState.Moved:
                    //smth
                    break;
                case TouchLocationState.Released:
                    //smth
                    break;
            }
        }
```

When double tap gesture is used this code calls Pressed -> Released -> DoubleTap -> Pressed
I want to handle only double tap case. how to fix this?
Feel sorry for my english, hope my question is clear. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that the only possible way to do that, is to code up your own input without using TouchPanel.EnabledGestures.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid handling the simple touch event after handling the gestures, add a Boolean flag that you set at the beginning of your touch handling to `true`, lets call it `handleSimpleTouch`. If you process a gesture, set `handleSimpleTouch` to false. Then before you process a simple touch, check the valu of `handleSimpleTouch`, if it's true, then process normally, otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: actualy i tried this 
if (Consts.TouchCollection.Count == 1 && !isGesture)   
but it doesnt solve the problem. To be more clear here is example:
i draw rectangle1, if i detect simple touch i draw one more rectangle2, if i detect gesture double tap i rotate this rectangle1. And here my problem, i got blinking rectangle2 which handle simple touch, because before xna detect double tap, it handles simple touch, any ideas, what im doing wrong?

Comment: With bool flag like this  if (Consts.TouchCollection.Count == 1) touch cycle when u double tap is Pressed -> Released -> DoubleTap -> Pressed
With bool flag like this if (Consts.TouchCollection.Count == 1 && !isGesture) cycle is Pressed -> Released ->DoubleTap. And this still didnt work